# How to perform the equivalent of a JOIN with Parse Query

Tags: sql, join, parse-platform

I have tables called `Groups`, `User` and `GroupsUsers`.

Rows in `GroupsUsers` contain three items: a typical `id`, a `userId` and a `groupId`. This means that `userId` is a member of `groupId`.

**I want to get all of the groups that a User is a member of** (not just the `groupId` but the actual group record from `Groups`).

If this were SQL, I would just say something like

```
SELECT Groups.id, Groups.name, Groups.size, Groups.headquarters, Groups.description
FROM GroupUsers, Groups
WHERE GroupsUsers.userId = 5 AND GroupsUsers.groupId = Groups.id
```

However in Parse it seems there is no way to do it. It seems the only way is to first do a Query on GroupsUsers, and then do a series of `n` queries to get the data about each `Group`. This can be dozens of Queries, which is ridiculous.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That's an outdated way to express it even with sql. The A,B join syntax has been deprecated since the sql-92 standard (more than 20 years).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn so I'm a bit outdated in SQL, but you get the idea